# During execution of ShinyApp, NULL is interpreted as "NA" inside a function

Tags: r, shiny

`forms.R`

```
form <- function(defaults){
    if(missing(defaults)){
        defaults <- list()
        defaults$random_value <- NULL
    }
    print(paste("This is the value", defaults$random_value))
    return(
        fluidPage(
        #<...columns...>
        dateInput("id", "Date Input", defaults$random_value)
        #<...columns...>
        )
    )
}
```

Results in `` Warning: Couldn't coerce the `value` argument to a date string with format yyyy-mm-dd ``
which is due to `random_value` being equal to `"NA"`

```
[1] "This is the value NA"
```

I have some `textInput` fields with this default value but it makes no sense as can be is seen, current value is clearly marked as `NULL` or the default date for the `dateInput` field. Error is not reproducible in the console, nor I think without the whole app that I have been working on. This has to be related to R local environments or something to do with ShinyApp itself. However, `ls` return just `defaults` which contain no value for `random_value`.

```
print(defaults)
$other_value
[1] "NA"
$another_value
[1] "NA"
```

How would I force R to interpret code correctly or fix the issue somehow? Code base is quite large and form file is sourced to `server.R`.

`server.R`

```
source("forms.R")
server <- function(input, output){
    
    observeEvent(input$form_type,{
        # If there exists starting value
        # they are passed to form() which is not the
        # case here when problematic form_type chosen
        output$dynamic_value <- renderUI({form()})
    })
}
```

Comment: This works for me. You should provide a full reproducible example. Note that the code `defaults$random_value <- NULL` does not set `NULL` to the field `random_value` of the `defaults` list, its effect is to delete this field (you can try in the console). But this is useless to set `NULL`, since `defaults$random_value` is `NULL` if there's no field `random_value`.

Comment: Yes as it is said it works on the console but not inside my `shinyApp`. I have no clue how to produce said sample because this. I understand this and try to `NULL` the `"NA"` given by the program. I have resorted to using `Sys.Date()` to remove the `"NA"` but the interpreter is so clearly broken I can't help but to wonder why it doesn't work.

Comment: That's not normal. For me it works in Shiny. I can't reproduce the behavior you describe. Provide a full example, so that we can reproduce, if you want us to be able to help you.